# How to get the string representation of a ShortCut Key including the SHIFTSTATE?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, delphi-10.4-sydney

In a Delphi 10.4.2 Win32 VCL Application, and based on the question + solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66563370/how-to-show-numeric-keypad-for-menu-item-shortcut-assigned-with-vk-numpad0) which provides a way to get the string representation of a Shortcut Key (but presumably with no possibility to also pass a SHIFTSTATE for the Shortcut Key) I wrote this code:

```
function MyGetSpecialShortcutName(ShortCut: TShortCut): string;
// gets shortcut name for e.g. VK_NUMPAD0 where TMenuItem.Shortcut gets the wrong shortcut name
var
  ScanCode: Integer;
  KeyName: array[0..255] of Char;
begin
  Result := '';
  FillChar(KeyName, SizeOf(KeyName), 0);
  ScanCode := Winapi.Windows.MapVirtualKey(LoByte(Word(ShortCut)), 0) shl 16;
  if ScanCode <> 0 then
  begin
    if Winapi.Windows.GetKeyNameText(ScanCode, KeyName, Length(KeyName)) <> 0 then
      Result := KeyName;
  end;
end;

function GetSpecialShortcutNameWithShiftState(const AScanCode: Word; const AShiftState: System.Classes.TShiftState = []): string;
begin
  Result := MyGetSpecialShortcutName(Vcl.Menus.ShortCut(AScanCode, AShiftState));
end;
```

Usage:

```
Result := GetSpecialShortcutNameWithShiftState(VK_A, [ssCTRL]);
```

However, the Result is "A" where the expected Result should be "CTRL+A".

How to get the string representation of a ShortCut Key including the SHIFTSTATE?

Comment: Do you need the modifiers to be localised? (For instance, "Ctrl+A" in English and "Strg+A" in German.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP wants the key names *fully localised*, but for completeness I first show that the VCL already has a function to obtain a partly unlocalised string, namely, [`ShortCutToText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.ShortCutToText) in the `Menus` unit:

```pascal
ShortCutToText(ShortCut(Ord('A'), [ssShift, ssAlt]))
```

This returns `Shift+Alt+A` on all systems.

Now, using the Win32 function [`GetKeyNameText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeynametexta) already mentioned in the Q, it is easy to obtain a fully localised shortcut string:

```pascal
function GetKeyName(AKey: Integer): string;
var
  name: array[0..128] of Char;
begin
  FillChar(name, SizeOf(name), 0);
  GetKeyNameText(MapVirtualKey(AKey, 0) shl 16, @name[0], Length(name));
  Result := name;
end;

function ModifierVirtualKey(AModifier: Integer): Integer;
begin
  case AModifier of
    Ord(ssShift):
      Result := VK_SHIFT;
    Ord(ssCtrl):
      Result := VK_CONTROL;
    Ord(ssAlt):
      Result := VK_MENU;
  else
    Result := 0;
  end;
end;

function ShortcutToString(AKey: Integer; AShiftState: TShiftState = []): string;
begin
  Result := '';
  for var Modifier in AShiftState do
  begin
    var ModifierKey := ModifierVirtualKey(Ord(Modifier));
    if ModifierKey <> 0 then
      Result := Result + IfThen(not Result.IsEmpty, '+') + GetKeyName(ModifierKey);
  end;
  Result := Result + IfThen(not Result.IsEmpty, '+') + GetKeyName(AKey);
end;
```

(Here I use a [`IfThen` overload](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.IfThen) from `StrUtils`.)

Now,

```pascal
ShortcutToString(Ord('A'), [ssShift, ssAlt])
```

returns `SKIFT+ALT+A` on my Swedish system. `SKIFT` is, as you might already have guessed, the Swedish name for the `SHIFT` key.

Comment: Trivia: virtually no German person knows the locale name for `SHIFT` (it's `UMSCHALT`) - everybody also uses this english term. Same for `ENTER`. On the contrary the locale `STRG` (for `CTRL`) is mostly assumed to stand for "Strong" or "String".

Comment: @AmigoJack I think you are wrong. Not all Germans are stupid.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand This is the most complete `ShortcutToString` function because in addition to the Key Name it also processes the Modifiers! Very nice code!